# How to enforce type-safety when creating a collection of types where each type must belong to the same parent class?

Tags: java, types, collections, subclass, type-safety

**Summary of the problem**

I would like to store a list of object types but stipulate that all the types are subclasses of a particular parent class. For example something like the following:

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    ...

}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass {
    ...

}

public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
    ...

}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    List<Type> listOfChildClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void someMethod() {
        listOfChildClassTypes.add(ChildClass1.class);
        listOfChildClassTypes.add(ChildClass2.class);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to define the listOfChildClassTypes list such that only sub-types of ParentClass can be added to it - any attempt to add a type that is not a sub-class of ParentClass should result in a compiler error. By using the generic 'Type' class, the code above allows any type to be stored in the list which will require runtime validation to check. This I would like to avoid.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I would like to store a list of object types but stipulate that all the types are subclasses of a particular parent class." <- Maybe I understand you wrong, but a simple  `List<ParentClass>` sounds like all you need. or why would a list like that not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: "*By using the generic 'Type' keyword ...*" - there is no such keyword in Java. --- `List<ParentClass> listOfChildClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes there is a 'Type' keyword. I am using it on java 11.

Comment: [No, there is not.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

Comment: Ok, I have java code in front of me that is running using a Map<Type,String> but you obviously know better :)

Comment: You are most probably misinterpreting the code. What is most probably used is the class [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html), which is not a keyword.

Comment: Anyway I think they're trying to have a list of classes, not of instances. That's why `List<ParentClass>` wouldn't fit.

Comment: yes correct, it is a list of class types not the class instances themselves

Comment: Have changed 'keyword' to 'class' as per @Turing85 comment

Comment: This is not possible with `Type`. It is, however, possible with `Class`: `List<Class<? extends Parent>> listOfChildClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();` ([ideone demo](https://ideone.com/CuiK8U)).

Comment: It works with Type but allows any type to be added to the list.  Your answer however is what I was looking for i.e. it restricts the class types to only those that are subclasses of the parent class. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read what `PECS` is and what "bounded types" are, because that is exactly what you need here :

```
List<Class<? extends ParentClass>> listOfChildClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: OP uses `Type`, not `Class`.

Comment: @Turing85 right, but it is not possible with `Type`.

Comment: Well I can add any type to the list when using Type but that isn't what I wanted

Comment: @user3855422 `Type` is rarely needed, though it is very useful sometimes. You case is not such an exception

Comment: Thanks Turing85 and @Eugene. Yes, just to be clear - I do not want to use Type. I was looking for a better way. Happy with the solution, thanks to you both.